# Array de objetos

Tags: java

Estou com um trabalho de facul e o professor pediu para dividir grupos e cada um procurar sobre um assunto escolhido por ele relacionado a java e:

O que é uma array de objetos no java?

Comment: Não creio que ela esteja duplicada, pois ele quer saber o que é um array de objetos em Java. Uma resposta bem básica, pensa em um objeto, exemplo um carro.
Carro, possui, cor, tipo, marca;
Quando você cria um array de objetos você faz da seguinte forma List<Carro> carros; nesse caso você esta criando um array onde você terá acesso a todos os itens do objeto Carro.

Comment: muito obrigado ^^

Comment: @Edjane o que voce explicou esta descrito nas duas duplicatas, nao tao resumido, mas está.